# differentiating between the best proper , polished sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Would you please take a light on if the bold parts have been selected properly?

Meanwhile, could you please show me which one of the sentences is recognised as the best sentence naturally?

A. In advanced and industrial countries, **under** economic and constant circumstance as well as change in society and behavioural patterns, the young's tendency towards marriage has been significantly reduced.

B.In advanced and industrial countries, **through** economic and constant circumstance as well as change in society and behavioural patterns, the young's tendency towards marriage has been significantly reduced.

C. In advanced and industrial countries, under economic and constant circumstance as well as change in society and behavioural patterns, the young's **interest** in marriage has been significantly reduced.

Any comment would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as far as I can see is that none of them seems to be really "correct".  One of the confusions is that you are using "...countries, [preposition] **economic and constant circumstance** as well..."

I do not really understand what you're trying to say here.  Perhaps a wording like this might help you more:

"In advanced and industrial countries, **through economic circumstance and constant change,** as well as change in society and behavioural patterns, the young's **tendency towards** [this is more formal, but "interest in" would also be acceptable] marriage has been significantly reduced."

Comment: Thank and what is your idea as to this version? "In advanced and industrial countries, through economic ideal and constant circumstance  as well as change in society and behavioural patterns, the young's tendency towards

Comment: ?? any other comment?

Comment: Hello.  Sorry, I didn't realize this had come through until I received an email today.  My comment revolves around this: what are you trying to say with the "constant circumstance"?  The phrase "constant circumstance" refers to a circumstance that is constant and unchanging, yet the rest of your sentence is referring to change in the situation.  Therefore, I'm having a hard time understanding to what you are referring with that phrase.  Perhaps a little more context might help?